# Automatic Library Extraction from Java Source Code

Tags: library, java, code-analysis, source-code

I´m working on a Java source code analyzer and need to analyze about 50 Java projects.

To analyze these projects I need to add the libs which are used in this projects. I do not have to build the whole project, I only need a **list of libs used in the project**, by looking at/parsing the source code.

Is there any tool which is able to **find and list (and maybe download)** the required libraries, by analyzing the source code?

Comment: You're building a source code analyzer, and you need a source code analyzer?  ... By library, I assume you mean "jar file", or do you just mean any source files imported but not part of the project?   What if the "project" already includes jar files?  I assume that if one library uses another, you want to find and list those, too?

Comment: This is not a particularly good SR request.  What OS? Invoked how? Any other constraints?  See http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information/352#352

Comment: Is parsing the pom an option ?

Comment: This guy hasn't been back since he posted the question over two weeks ago; no clarification to the question.